# Count distinct on field value

Tags: sql

I have a specific problem to count and do an operation on fields on MySQL database. I cannot describe the situation well because there are some specific things I need to do. Let's take an example

```
name | quantity(varchar)
----------------------
Test    10
Bar     5
Foo     2
Test    5
Bar     5
Foo     10
Bar     5
Foo     5
```

What I want is to select the count for each name and show only one name per line with the total. I have to cast the text to integer. But I don't want to specify the WHERE name='xyz' (because I will have many many names). I tried to do a query that will select all the names and the total.

```
Name | Total
----------------------
Test     15
Foo      17
Bar      15
```

And so on if there are +100 distinct names.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What have you tried so far??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sum and group by for that:

```
   select name, sum(quantity) from yourTable group by name;
```